# Styling emails with Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I am using Outlook 2013 and want to stylize my emails. Background color, container background color, container border-radius, container padding. I've tried stationary and other tricks, but they don't meet my requirements.

I'm looking for some dynamic trick that my writing area should be clean. Please see this screenshot, which is exactly what I want:

[image]

Comment: That's much easier to do with something like MailChimp.

Comment: Yeah DavidPostill!
But can i make in outlook?

Comment: It depends. Outlook supports only a subset of html and css.

Answer (score 1):

#### Can I create an email in Outlook using all the features of HTML and CSS?

Outlook only supports a subset of HTML and CSS.

- This hasn't changed since Outlook 2007
- The rendering engine is the same in Outlook 2013.
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx) documents the support for HTML and CSS.
- [The Ultimate Guide to CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) documents what CSS is supported by Outlook. You can see that a lot is missing.

---

> If you’ve been designing and coding emails for a few years now, you’re likely aware of Outlook’s dismal support for email standards. Microsoft switched to Word (from Internet Explorer) as its rendering engine with the introduction of Outlook 2007 and hasn’t looked back (errr, forward?) since. Despite the email community’s efforts and a well-intentioned response from Microsoft, this means that HTML and CSS support in Outlook has remain virtually unchanged between versions 2007, 2010 and now 2013.

Source [Outlook 2013 Still Powered by Word; Now Available for Email Testing](https://litmus.com/blog/outlook-2013-still-powered-by-word-now-available-for-email-testing)